# email with google docs

Tags: mysql, email, vba, google-docs

i have a spreadsheet on google docs. one of the fields in the google docs is an EMAIL field. i need to be able to send the email to everyone on the spreadsheet every day at a certain time. is there an easy solution for this? can i have VBA access google docs? does google doc have an API?

i found this:
http://code.google.com/googleapps/appsscript/class_mailapp.html#sendEmail

using the above link i would i go through every row in the spreadsheet using a loop and send an email to every email

Comment: Are you related to Jon Skeet?

Comment: @radek yes he's my sister's son's neice

Comment: this is how we are related http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sister's+son's+niece

Comment: we share 6.25% blood; however, i got the good looks, and he got the brains

Answer (score 2):

Google App Script is certainly able to solve your requirement. It has similar syntax to VB Scripts.

First you need to add a script that is able to go over the list of emails in the range in the spreadsheet:

```
// The code below will get all the sheets
var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
for (var i = 0; i > sheets.length; i++) {
    var range = sheet[i].getRange(...);
    for (var row = range.getRowIndex(); row < range.getLastRow(); row++) {
        // assuming that the format of the range is "name, email"
        var name = range.getCell(row,range.getColumnIndex()).getValue();
        var email = range.getCell(row,range.getColumnIndex()+1).getValue();
        var subject = ...;
        var body = "Dear " + name + ", ...";
        // with the optAdvancedArgs you can add attachments and other goodies
        MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, optAdvancedArgs);
    }
}
```

Second you need to trigger this script to run every day at the specified time:

from: http://code.google.com/googleapps/appsscript/guide_events.html

- Choose Triggers > Current script's triggers. You see a panel with the message No triggers set up. Click here to add one now.
- Click the link.
- Under Run, select the function you want executed on schedule.
- Under Events, select Time-driven.
- On the first drop-down list that appears, select Week timer, Day timer, Hour timer, or Minutes timer. Depending on which you select, you see one or two additional lists. To test the trigger and your function, you might want to pick a short duration so that you can see the execution without having to wait hours or days.
- If you picked Week timer, select a day of the week and time of day.
- If you picked Day timer, select an hour.
- If you picked Hour timer, select an interval of hours.
- If you picked Minutes timer, select an interval of minutes.
- Click Save.
- To ensure that the script runs at the correct time for a particular time zone, click File > Properties, select a time zone, and click Save.

Answer (score 1):

Pull down the column menu by clicking on the column header of the email column.  Choose Copy.  Open your email program and paste into the "to" field.  Works with outlook, anyway.